# How to call nameless function from contract, say "fallback" function(){}

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, myetherwallet

I mean I am using myetherwallet and there I paste the ABI, yet the ABI has all functions described except the function (){}, so should I make up some name and just call it, would this ever work or? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually fallback functions are used as payable to receive Ethers just like a normal account receiving payments.
Moreover, this function may be called due to an invalid function call, so yes you can test it by specifying an arbitrary function name.

Comment: OK, my thoughts exacfrly but i was thinking that this may be too 'excentric' to work, so I'll try anyway.